# C# XML documentation '<include>' tag not appearing in intellisense?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, comments, intellisense

I developing a C# class library in Visual Studio, and I have been making use of XML Documentation Comments primarily for their integration with Intellisense. However, the bulk of comments has become quite cluttered, so now I am endeavoring to use the `<include>` tag, and an external XML document to reduce the clutter.

My issue is that when using the `<include>` tag Intellisense seems to not update with the information, not show any of the `<summary>` and `<param>` tags that I've assigned to some of my classes and methods.

For Example I could have a class 'Test' documented as shown:

```
/// <include file="docs.xml" path='extradoc/class[@name="Test"]/*' />
        class Test { string foo = "bar"; }
```

And have docs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<extradoc>
  <class name="Test">
    <summary>
      Contains some Foo.
    </summary>
  </class>
</extradoc>
```

And upon build the output XML populates correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Example Program</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:Example_Program.Program.Test">
            <summary>
      Contains some Foo.
    </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

The only issue is that, try as I might, this documentation *will not* appear in the intellisense boxes while appending my code. Is there some Visual Studio configuration setting I'm missing? I've scoured the msn documentation to no avail.

Comment: Not sure if this helps - but generally restarting VS and deleting an user options file has helped me with this in the past, though it was just general intellisense in my case.

Comment: A bit confused about `this documentation will not appear in the intellisense boxes while appending my code`, Do you mean when you reference this assembly in another project, the intellisense in that project can't recognize the documentation of your assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue is that when using the  tag Intellisense seems to
>   not update with the information, not show any of the  and
>    tags that I've assigned to some of my classes and methods.

1.**Avoid that your issue is being not able to see `summary` in Intellisense in current project A.**

You can get help from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc), this technology is used to provide better reading experience. So assuming you have the `Test` class in current priject `A`, when you see the content in VS code editor, you'll see something like:

[image]

It's expected behavior that you won't see that rich comments in project A any more cause they have been moved to `docs.xml`.

2.**If you mean when you create a new Project B(or share the assembly to other developers), the Intellisense can't recognize your Test class.**

Two possible causes:

1.The output xx.dll and xx.xml from project A are  not in the same folder, so when you reference that xx.dll in your new project, Intellisense won't display the documentation comments.

2.I guess there's something wrong with your `docs.xml` file. (I can't find any official document which indicates this technology supports user-defined nodes like `extradoc` and `class` in docs.xml, I used these two nodes and the Intellisense did not work, after changing them to normal `docs` and `members`, it works now)

**Try using `docs.xml` and `include` in this way:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<docs>
  <members name="MyTests">
    <Test>
      <summary>
        This class is public, but do nothing
      </summary>
      <remarks>
        Just write something here to indicate this is remarks.
      </remarks>
    </Test>
  </members>
</docs>
```

and

```
/// <include file="docs.xml" path='docs/members[@name="MyTests"]/Test/*' />
    public class Test { }
```

I suggest you use a public class to test... After that create a new project and reference that xx.dll, when calling `Test` class you can see the summary:

[image]

And if we F12 we can see detailed comments:

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: _It's expected behavior that you won't see that rich comments in project A any more cause they have been moved to docs.xml._  This is a pretty stupid design, which is hopefully going to be changed soon: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4279